# Is there an easy way to change a device in QTCaptureSession

Tags: objective-c, qtkit

Is there an easy way to change an audio/video device in QTCaptureSession other than enumarating over an array of devices from...

```
[captureSession inputs];
```

Checking to see whether the device is QTMediaTypeSound or QTMediaTypeVideo and deleting them?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you mean by "easy".

From the top of my head, there are the following options:

1. Have an instance variable for the inputs you want to remove later, in the first place.
2. Query the array returned from `-[QTCaptureSession inputs]` by sending `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"device.mediaType == \"%@\"", type]` to it.
3. If you are targeting ≥ 10.6 you have the added option of using `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` to determine the inputs you want to remove.

But there is no way (at least none, that I know of) of saying `removeInputsWithMediaType:`.

HTH

Daniel